# Maximum minimum and mean in Datalog

Tags: database, recursion, logic, logic-programming, datalog

I cannot figure how calculate a mean, maximum and minimum using Datalog declarative logic programming language.

Eg. Considering this simple schema

```
Flows(Stream, River)
Rivers(River, Length)
```

If I want

a) the mean length of the rivers,

b) the longest river,

c) and the river with less Streams

what are the right Datalog queries?

I have read the Datalog theory, but cannot figure how these simple in another language queries could be solved with Datalog and haven't found any similar sample.

NOTE
The datalog that I use is with basic arithmetic functions like `y is z+1`, `y is z-1`, `y is z\1` or `y is z*1`, and you can use `X<Y` or `Y>X` statements, and negation, so theoretically should be possible to do this kind of interrogation in some way since It has enough expressive power.

Answer (score 1):

Is negation supported or not? If so, we can do max (or min) as follows:

```
shorterRivers(R1, L1) :- Rivers(R1, L1), Rivers(R2, L2), L1 < L2.
longestRivers(R1, L1) :- Rivers(R1, L1), !shorterRivers(R1,L1).
```

"mean" will be harder to do, as it require "SUM" and "COUNT" aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Datalog supports first-order logic only, which does not include aggregate functions.  However, some datalog implementations, such as pyDatalog, supports aggregate functions as an extension.

Comment: The datalog that I use is with basic arithmetic functions  like `y is z+1` or  `y is z*1` and so on, and you can use `X<Y` or `Y>X` statements, so theoretically should be possible to do this kind of interrogation in some way since It has enough expressive power.

Comment: Trust me, it is not possible in standard Datalog, without extensions for aggregation.  Datalog is not Turing complete.  See also Datalog entry in Wikipedia.

Comment: As I have said is not the standard Datalog and supports these operations

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite positive there's no way of finding the mean using datalog, or of counting values, so questions a) and c) probably aren't possible. And with your specifications, the min and max values also seem to be impossible to find.

With your specifications, you might try the following

```
b) Longest river

// THE FOLLOWING IS INCORRECT
Result(River) ::=
    Rivers(River, Length)
    and Rivers(__, AllLengths)
    and Length >= AllLengths
```

But notice that this finds any two pairs of Rivers where one has greater than or equal length, but not the longest.

You didn't mention this, but included in datalog are "universal quantifiers" which allow you to operate on all values for a particular data column. This involves using the FORALL (∀) symbol. You must also use implication (->) to construct a statement that is only true if your river's length is greater than all other river lengths. You should be able to do this like so:

```
b) the longest river

Result(River) ::=
    Rivers(River, Length)
    and (∀AllLengths, Rivers(__, AllLengths) -> Length >= AllLengths)
```

I don't know of any way that you could do questions a) and c) using this method. They a) requires that you get the sum of values in a particular column, and c) that you count the number of columns matching a particular value, and this might be impossible given Datalog's set semantics.